# Suspending a process in bash running inside console2

Tags: windows, bash, background-process, console2

In other terminals I would press `Ctrl+z` to suspend an application, often to then issue `bg` to send it into background.

In console2 `Ctrl+z` does nothing, probably because the key combination has a different meaning in Windows. But is there a way to achieve the same effect, save for 'process &'?

(I know I should use `&` and it works, but sometimes I would setup shell, start an editor, begin editing, then return to the console just to find that I forgot the `&` and I can't use the shell. It annoys me that I then have to either open a new shell and set it up again, or quit the editor, start it with `&` and set it up again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This annoying issue surely is a console2 bug. You may find something about at its issue tracker.

Anyway, what `ctrl+z` does is send a `SIGSTOP` signal to current process. So, you can still  send that signal from another session/tab. (If it is less annoying than stop and start with `&`).
To do that, you can use the `kill` command.

```
kill -s SIGSTOP pid
```

(pid is the process PID number)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 18):

In Console2, ctrl-c is bound by default to copy (text) you have to press ctrl-shift-c to cancel job.

Comment: and does ctrl+shift-z suspend a job? (that's what I was asking). NB I don't use windows / console2 anymore, so I can't check myself.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift-z or Ctrl-z do not work for me. Ctrl+Shift+c works.

Answer (score 10):

You could also try to remove the hotkey that is conflicting with `ctrl+z`.

I was having trouble using `ctrl+c` to cancel the execution of a script. As soon as I removed that hotkey, `ctrl+c` had its default restored and I was able to cancel executions properly.

Comment: do you mean a hot key somewhere in console2 preferences, or elsewhere in windows?

Comment: Sorry if I expressed it bad. I meant the one accessible through Console2's preferences. If you remove the action that is bound to that key combination, their default behavior is going to be restored.